# How to change the URL and content without refresh website using reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I came across the site https://hashnode.com/. When we click any topic it updates the URL and content without refreshing the site.

I know we can update the content using states and props without refresh.

How to change the URL at the same time?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Y82.png)

Comment: typo error. I have updated now

Answer (score 1):

That's what React Router is for.

**`Routes.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import FirstPage from './pages/FirstPage';
import SecondPage from './pages/SecondPage';

class Routes extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return(
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/page-1" component={FirstPage} />
                 <Route exact path="/page-2" component={SecondPage} />
             </Switch>
         )
    }
}
```

**`App.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import store from "./Store";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Routes from "./Routes";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component
{

    render()
    {
        return (

            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>

        )
    }
}

export default App;
```